# android:staggergridlayout while moving up shuffles

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, staggeredgridlayout

I am using staggered grid layout. the following is the code:

```
StaggeredGridLayoutManager glm= new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
glm.setGapStrategy(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_NONE);
```

I am using `GAP_HANDLING_NONE` to avoid images swapping from one column to other.

When I start the app, the beginning of the screen is:

[image]

After scrolling down to bottom and when I return to the top. randomly the following three images show the layout (it keeps varying)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please paste adapter and other important codes

Answer (score 6):

Staggered grids are likely to have gaps at the edges of the layout. To avoid these gaps, [StaggeredGridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager?hl=en) can offset spans independently or move items between spans. You can control this behavior via `setGapStrategy(int)`:

```
StaggeredGridLayoutManager sGrid = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
sGrid.setGapStrategy(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_MOVE_ITEMS_BETWEEN_SPANS);
```

I hope this will help a buddy.

Comment: I tried this but it still moves the images. There are suspicions that the size of the view is clearly not set in the layout, and since wrap wrap is there, the width and height are 0 at the moment when the glide loads the image, due to which the manager constantly mixes the view between positions.

Comment: @maXp Please try my answer.Are you check this?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

Add this **Override methode** in your Adapter

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

If this solution is not work for you!

**Try below solution**

I am using **StaggeredGridLayout** for getting all gallery images and it's working fine for me.

**- Main Activity**

```
/*Init Gallery Photos RecyclerView*/
gallerySglm = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, RecyclerView.VERTICAL);
gallerySglm.setGapStrategy(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_MOVE_ITEMS_BETWEEN_SPANS);
binding.rvGalleryImg.setLayoutManager(gallerySglm);
galleryPhotosAdapter = new GalleryPhotosAdapter(context, galleryPhotoArrayList);
binding.rvGalleryImg.setAdapter(galleryPhotosAdapter);
galleryPhotosAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
/*End Init Gallery Photos RecyclerView*/
```

**- Item Layout**

Add ImageView inside **ConstraintLayout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/mainCard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/main_bg"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_5sdp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="false"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_2sdp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/clMain"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/img"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</layout>
```

**- Adapter**

```
public class GalleryPhotosAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GalleryPhotosAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> arrayList;
    private ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();

    public GalleryPhotosAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> arrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public GalleryPhotosAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        ItemGalleryPhotosBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()),
                R.layout.item_gallery_photos, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(binding);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final GalleryPhotosAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        //Set size
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(arrayList.get(position), options);

        String ratio = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%d:%d", options.outWidth, options.outHeight);
        set.clone(holder.binding.clMain);
        set.setDimensionRatio(holder.binding.img.getId(), ratio);
        set.applyTo(holder.binding.clMain);
        //End set size

        Glide.with(context)
                .load(arrayList.get(position))
                .into(holder.binding.img);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ItemGalleryPhotosBinding binding;

        public ViewHolder(ItemGalleryPhotosBinding binding) {
            super(binding.getRoot());
            this.binding = binding;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this can help You!

Thank You.

Comment: @maXp Are you check my answer?If it is not working for you then tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple solustion for your problem.

```
    StaggeredGridLayoutManager straggerGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    straggerGridLayoutManager .setGapStrategy(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_MOVE_ITEMS_BETWEEN_SPANS);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(straggerGridLayoutManager);

    dataList = YourDataList (Your Code for Arraylist);

    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerAdapter = new DataAdapter(dataList, recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);


    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new ScrollListener());
```

Create class for Custom **RecyclerView Scroll Listener**.

```
    private class ScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {
       @Override
       public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            recyclerView.invalidateSpanAssignments();
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice the sample code I provided for you

Images are shown in different proportions based on their dimensions and even some apps show a mixed view of images and videos like Instagram. In the coming tutorial, we will be experiencing such a view where videos are loaded and played with autoplay features when we strolled onto the video view.

When it comes to the implementation technically there is no much difference in regular style of showing images to this staggering view.

> Activity_main.Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="staggered.android.com.staggeredview.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/stagRecycleView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

> Recyclerview_row.Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

> MainActivity.Java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<Integer> Image;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Image = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
                R.drawable.img1,R.drawable.img2,
                R.drawable.img3,R.drawable.img4,
                R.drawable.img5,R.drawable.img6,
                R.drawable.img7,R.drawable.img8,
                R.drawable.img9,R.drawable.img10,
                R.drawable.img1,R.drawable.img2,
                R.drawable.img3,R.drawable.img4,
                R.drawable.img5,R.drawable.img6,
                R.drawable.img7,R.drawable.img8,
                R.drawable.img9)
        );

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.stagRecycleView);

        layoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, Image);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


}
```

**And finally**

> RecyclerViewAdapter.Java

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<Integer> Image;
    Context context;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Integer> Image) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.Image = Image;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_row, viewGroup, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        viewHolder.imgview.setImageResource(Image.get(i));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return Image.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ImageView imgview;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imgview = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgView);

        }
    }
}
```

**I hope this will help you ;)**